# How to generate dashboard from multiple data source using Google studio?

Tags: android, google-analytics, looker-studio

I have an android application used by multiple companies. I need to use google analytics data and list of features in application to identify features which are not used by a company.

Say below is the list of features in the application

- Feature A
- Feature B
- Feature C
- Feature D

Usage of these features is being captured as events with google analytics.

So if XYZ company is using only Feature A & B, need to show report as

XYZ Company

Unused features

- Feature C
- Feature D

I have used google analytics add-on in google sheets to pull event analytics data and have all application features in another sheet.

As google data studio allows only one data source not able to figure out how to get the desired result by combining this data.

Can someone please guide me in right direction ?

TIA

Comment: Data Studio allows one source per widget, but multiple sources per report. When in doubt you can always combine data in a spreadsheet and then use that as data source for Data Studio. However I am not quite sure if this is on topic, as it is not a programming problem as such.

Answer (score 1):

You are right In data studio we can use only 1 data source, I would like to suggest you use google analytics API's .

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten around this problem by downloading the data from the different sources into Google Sheets, then combining them (through automated formulas, if possible) onto another worksheet. I then use that worksheet as my DS datasource.